# How to print escape character "\" in java?

Tags: java

How to print a graphic in java using escape character ""?
System.out.println("  \ "); etc..

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjcSu.png)

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/

Answer (score 3):

You escape `\` with a second `\` like `\\` and (if using Java 13+) you can use [triple quotes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/355).

```
String msg = """
        \\   /
         \\ /
          X
         / \\
        /   \\
        """;
System.out.println(msg);
```

Outputs

```
\   /
 \ /
  X
 / \
/   \
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a escape character. To print the literal character, you need to escape it itself. Replace every `\` with `\\` and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you all for your support in resolving this